# Divergence of charge velocity

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

$$
\mathbf J=\sigma \mathbf E
\\\rho \mathbf v=\sigma \mathbf E
$$

Taking the divergence of both sides:
$$
\rho\nabla\cdot\mathbf v=\sigma\nabla\cdot\mathbf E
$$

Subsituting $\nabla\cdot\mathbf E = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon}$, we get that the divergence of the velocity of the charge inside a conductor is equal to the conductivity:
$$
\nabla\cdot\mathbf v = \frac{\sigma}{\epsilon}
$$

Can anyone explain what the significance of this is? And if this fact is used anywhere?

Comment: Possibly related: [Interpreting divergence of velocity field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2192755/interpreting-divergence-of-velocity-field)

Comment: Also, $\nabla\cdot(\rho\mathbf{v})\neq\rho\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v}$ since $\rho$ is generally not a constant, but has space dependence.

Comment: Indeed as dandan states $\nabla \cdot (\rho v)= \rho (\nabla \cdot v)+(v \cdot \nabla) \rho$